# Rank a particlar column

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table, having employees id,name,salary. I want to rank the employees based on salary.

Table: employee

```
id   employee_name  employee_salary
------------------------------------
 1   Martin            3500
 2   Su                4000
 3   Alex              3500
 4   Flora             8000
```

my desired result is

```
id   employee_name   employee_salary   Rank
--------------------------------------------
 1   Martin            3500             3
 2   Su                4000             2
 3   Alex              3500             3
 4   Flora             8000             1
```

I tried using rank() function, the query is

```
select 
    salary, 
    rank() over (order by employee_salary desc) AS Rank 
from employee
```

This throws a mysql error:

> 3 errors were found during analysis.
>
> An alias was previously found. (near "Rank" at position 61)
> An alias was expected. (near " " at position 60)
> Unexpected token. (near "Rank" at position 61

Anything wrong with the query?

Comment: "An alias was previously found. (near "Rank" at position 61) An alias was expected. (near " " at position 60) Unexpected token. (near "Rank" at position 61`"   Doesn't look like a MySQL error to me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without using variable you could get rank as

```
select a.*,
  (select count(*) + 1 
   from employee 
   where employee_salary > a.employee_salary) as rank
from employee a
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/54844/5)

Mysql 8 has a support for [window functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html)

Comment: True but this query is slow because off the co-related subquery compared to the MySQL user variable solution especially when used on large tables

Comment: @raymond, true. table have 1M records.Any alternate

Comment: @AmitSharma Perhaps adding an index on `employee_salary` would help you

Comment: @junaid, worked great. but how to use the query if the table one is getting from joints

Comment: @AmitSharma can you post the original query ? Or you can ask a new one with all the details

Comment: posted as new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50509854/ranking-in-mysql-when-using-inner-join

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT id, employee_name, employee_salary, @rank := @rank + 1 AS Employee_rank FROM employee e, (SELECT @rank := 0) r ORDER BY employee_salary desc
```

The result  will be like this

[image]